# Is it possible to force 16:9 ratio in iPad emulation mode

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ipad, emulation

I noticed that when loading my app on the iPad pro simulator, it loads in 16:9 ratio, not 3:4.

Is it possible to force this behaviour also on the other iPads?

My app is designed for the 16:9 portrait ratio. It's not universal but apple will make the app available for download on the iPad in emulator mode. In those cases i want the app to display in 16:9, not the default 3:4

I've tried the following

```
float width = (9.0f/16.0f) * windowFrame.size.height;
CGRect mainRect = CGRectMake((windowFrame.size.width - width) / 2, 0, width, windowFrame.size.height);
[self.window setFrame:mainRect];
```

After detecting 3:4 ratio in appDelegate.

But I'm unsure if apple would refuse it or not it.